# Some of my windows registries(Vista) are not accessible due to permission violations. How to resolve it?

Tags: windows-vista

Some of my windows registry permissions have been changed.It denies access to services  like SQL Server. What is the issue here and how can it be resolved? Moreover I am able to login only in safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can change permissions using `regedit.exe`. Try clicking on a registry key and choosing the "Permissions" option. On my computer the permissions are set in the following way:

- the System group and the Administrators group - full control
- the Restricted group - read
- the Everyone group - read (on branches like HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)